# Rename files based on part of a file

Tags: linux, rename

How do I rename 2009-08-2009-08-13 to 2009-08-$my_var_till_2009-08-13 for multiple files? The 2009-08-13 portion changes with respect to the date of the file, so I need a way to grab that part of the filename. Could I use basename somehow?

Comment: on what      OS?

Comment: I am running this on a Linux OS

Answer (score 1):

If the file names are always in that date format, I think that something like this would work (in a script) - this is, of course, assuming that they are all in the same directory and '$my_var_till' is defined in the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd <name_of_target_directory>

for i in `ls`
do
    yyyy=`echo $i | awk -F- '{print $3}`'
    mm=`echo $i | awk -F- '{print $4}'`
    dd=`echo $i | awk -F- '{print $5}'`

    mv $i "$yyyy-$mm-$my_var_till-$yyyy-$mm-$dd"
done
```

if '$my_var_till' is not defined in the shell, you could take it as a command line argument (of course you might want to add some error checking with the argument):

```
#!/bin/bash

my_var_till=$1
<continue on with code from above>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the utility `rename` (there's several of these I think, I have the perl version):

```
rename -n -e 's/(\d{4}-\d{2})-([\d-]+)/$1'"$your_variable"'$2/' *
```

That `-n` flag means that `rename` doesn't change any files, it just shows you what would change. Remove it to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

[mmv](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/) can help:

> If you ever have to rename or move multiple files under Linux, then
>   the mmv shell command will make your life easy. The mmv utility will
>   also come in handy for copying multiple files, appending content of
>   one file to other files, as well as for creation of links.

Answer (score 0):

This script will rename any file with a name like

```
this: 2009-08-2009-08-13
to:   2009-08-${my_var_till}_2009-08-13
```

For example, if `my_var_till="whatever"`, and filename=`"2009-08-2009-08-13"`, then the result will be:

```
mv "2009-08-2009-08-13" "2009-08-whatever_2009-08-13"
```

Files with names that are not in that format will be skipped.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_var_till="whatever"

for f in *
    # test if file is proper format
    echo "${f}"|grep -E '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        n=$(echo ${f}|sed -r 's/^(.{8})(.{10})$/'"\1${my_var_till}_\2/")
        mv "${f}" "${n}"
    fi
done
```